# Jasmine - How to Write Test for Array with Named properties and Object

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I ran into a strange situation today, thanks to Javascript. I have a Object that look something like this.

```
$scope.main = [{main : 1},service:true];
```

Now when I try to expect this inside the jasmine test case for equating the Objects :

```
expect($scope.main).toEqual([{main : 1},service:true]);
```

This gives me an error :

```
Unexpected Token.
```

Strangely, This is a valid object for Javascript. But Jasmine is not able to accept that.

Is there any way to test this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT : Attaching a structure screenshot.**

[image: structure image]

Comment: This is supposed to pass, and it isn't for Angular (so I'm going to remove the tag). If it doesn't, please provide a [mcve] of your issue on a sandbox of your choice.

Comment: @trichetriche OK let me give you some steps. So, when you try to create this object upfront. you will get an error. To make this Array you have to add the points manually like :
$scope.main.= [];
$scope.main.service = true;
$scope.main[0]={main:1}

But in the case of jasmine Test case. When you are trying to create this object upfront. Javascript will give you and error (Can be verified in chrome console). and hence my question

Comment: What I meant is that `toEqual` works for equality and not memory reference (which would be `toBe`). If it doesn't, then please provide a [mcve].

Comment: And without wanting to insult you, don't blame jasmine for your mistakes : don't create an array with named properties and objects in it. If you want to keep this data, consider using a real object.

Comment: @trichetriche - I know this is a wrong way of doing thing. Problem is, I am working on a legacy application and it was written like this. Moreover, I am not blaming Jamine for this. Just want to know if there is a way to test these type of objects in Jasmine.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from rewriting it :) But you can also test single properties, such as `expect($scope.main.service).toBeTruthy();`, this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I see now based on your screenshot that you are creating the `main` object in multiple steps. I've shortened it to the following:

```
var main = [{main: 1}];
main.service = true;
```

In dev-tools, you are seeing `main` as something that looks like this: `[{main: 1}, service: true]`.

However, don't be mislead. Dev-tools is showing you a structure that is just meant to be informative. You can't actually create that structure in one line of javascript, because it is invalid. You have to create it in multiple steps, like you have.

This is why when you try to create it in your test in one line, you are getting an `Unexpected Token.` error. In your test, you have to create the expected object in a similar fashion to how you created your `main` object. For example:

```
var expected = [{main: 1}];
expected.service = true;

expect(main).toEqual(expected);
```

Comment: yes it is not valid if you make it in one go. Please refer the comments in the questions for steps to generate the array.

Comment: I've read the comments and they aren't correct. Your comment stating if you do this: `$scope.main.= []; $scope.main.service = true; $scope.main[0]={main:1}` doesn't create an object with this structure `[{main : 1},service:true]`. Nothing can create an object with that structure, because it is invalid javascript.

Comment: Pardon me there is no '.' after $scope.main, I did the same with var in chrome console and able to create that structure attaching a screenshot in the question.

Comment: You cannot create the structure you have in your screenshot with the javascript you have in your post... it is invalid javascript. You *can* create it with the javascript in my answer, which is valid javascript. You *can* test it with the javascript in my answer, which is also valid javascript. You asked why you were getting the unexpected token, I am giving you the answer.

Comment: @vaibhav - I see in your screenshot that you are creating it the way I said to create it, not the way you said you created it. The console is showing you what the structure looks like, but not as valid javascript. You can't take that structure and use it as javascript. When you do, you see the error you have. You need to create the expected object in the same manner as I have, or as you created the original object.

Comment: Got you. Thanks for taking an effort to clarify it to me. I conclude that this is more of a glitch that should have been avoided but survived somehow as javascript glitch ( I wish we had type checking before). I will refactor the code to remove it :) Thanks for helping.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you got it figured out.